# Paperclip invalid content type, even though I've allowed it in the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

My friend tried to upload an image to my website http://aspinteresting.com on her Lenovo mobile phone, and the app returned an '`invalid content type`' error. On her phone, the 'Details' of the photo said that the file was a "jpg" file.

However, as you can see, I have allowed for that in the Model:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => "x600>", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

 validates :image, presence: true
 validates :description, presence: true
end
```

This has me completely stumped. I've never seen this error from my app before, and many people have uploaded many different images to it now.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this?

Comment: I ended up removing the validation restriction temporarily.  Kind of annoying right? Haha